# sorting a hash in ruby with a extra condition

Tags: ruby

I have a hash like this

```
result_array = Hash[h.sort_by{|k, v| v}.reverse]
```

This result array will have the sorted value of the `h` hash. My problem is that when the value of two hashes are the same I want to check for a different condition. What should I do now?

---

Note that my key is an object called Vendor when you read the below.
The different condition is that if the values of two keys are the same. If the values of the keys are same I will do the comparision

```
if k.works.number_of_views > k.next.works.number_of_views
 k
else
 k.next
end
```

Comment: can you show an example of that "different condition"? a sample input would also help.

Comment: I think what you are saying is that if `h[k1] == h[k2]`, you want to order the hash elements with keys `k1` and `k2` by comparing `k1.next.works.number_of_views` with `k2.next.works.number_of_views`.  If that's correct, replace `some_condition(k, v)` in @tokland 's answer with `k.next.works.number_of_views`.  You might also edit your question to clarify, for the benefit of those who read it in future.

Answer (score 2):

Use a lexicographical ordering:

```
result_hash = Hash[h.sort_by { |k, v| [v, some_condition(k, v)] }.reverse]
```

Comment: please check the edited question. How do I add the if condition in this?

Comment: It's not clear in your question, if the second condition is the numbers of views, then: `[v, k.works.number_of_views]`.

Comment: The second condition is not the number of keys. If the value of the keys are eqaul then I will check if the k.works.number_of_views of the current key is greater than the k.next.number_of_views. I will return the one having the highest number_of_views. The key is a object of a model "Vendor".